# Inner join, error in foreach cycle

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, inner-join

I have a problem with linq query in c#. I write inner join for my two lists/collections:

```
var InnerJoin =
    from itemA in listA
    join itemB in listB
    on itemA equals itemB
    select new { itemA };
```

It is works for this one:

```
var listA = new List<string>() {"aaaa", "bbbb", "cccc", "dddd"};
var listB = new List<string>() { "zzzz", "bbbb"};
```

But i want to apply this for my Dictionaries

```
var parametrsSelected = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"kind", "favorite data"}
};

var parametrsAll = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    {"kind", "Null"}, {"id","Null"}, {"type","Null"}
};

var InnerJoinParam =
    from itemA in parametrsAll
    join itemB in parametrsSelected
        on itemA.Key equals itemB.Key
    select new { itemB };

if (InnerJoinParam.Count() == 0)
    return -1;
else
{
    parametrsAll.Clear();
    foreach (var pair in InnerJoinParam)
    {
        parametrsAll.Add(pair.itemB.Key, pair.itemB.Value);
    }
}
```

But i have a error: `InnerJoinParam.Count()` return a `Count = 1`, but the foreach loop is not executing. And perform operations following the loop. Why it's not work.

Comment: Quick tip, any time you do `someVar.Count() == 0` you can almost always replace it with `!someVar.Any()` and it will be faster (`someVar.Count() != 0` becomes `someVar.Any()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware of the fact that LINQ queries are not executed at the moment they are created, but at the moment they are evaluated (so when you access the results).
In your scenario you execute your query here:

```
foreach (var pair in InnerJoinParam)
```

But until you get there you have already cleared your `parametrsAll` so the query does not return any results when executed:

```
parametrsAll.Clear(); 
foreach (var pair in InnerJoinParam) //depends on parametrsAll
```

So you should ehter move the `parametrsAll.Clear()` after the `foreach` loop:

```
    else
    {
        var paramsList = new Dictionary<string,string>(); 
        foreach (var pair in InnerJoinParam)
        {
            paramsList.Add(pair.itemB.Key, pair.itemB.Value);
        }
        parametrsAll.Clear();
        parametrsAll = paramsList;
    }
```

Or simply evalute the results of your query before the foreach loop:

```
var results =
    from itemA in parametrsAll
    join itemB in parametrsSelected
        on itemA.Key equals itemB.Key
    select new { itemB };

var InnerJoinParam  = results.ToDictionary( x=> x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: You're right about evaluating the results before the loop, but casting to `Dictionary` won't do that.

Comment: You are right, my mistake, I have corrected my answer